# View appearing below status bar initially

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios9, uistatusbar

I have the following hierarchy in my app:
`UITabBarController (rootviewcontroller)` --> Custom `UINavigationController --> View1 (UIViewController)`

After updating to `iOS9`, Initially when app launches , the View 1 is shifted a bit below the status bar as below:

[image: shifted below]

Also, the `viewwillappear` doesn't get called by default. The custom navigation bar delegate methods are used within the custom class, no other delegate is used anywhere. Also I have used `RXCustomTabar` as the rootview. Help!

Comment: Try changing it on your info.plist

Comment: changing what? can you please tell

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps

1.In yourproject - info.plist

```
 Status bar is initially hidden  Boolean  YES
```

2.After that you need to do is in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of AppDelegate.m

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden=NO;
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) 
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
    [application setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    self.window.clipsToBounds=YES;
    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
}
else
{
    self.window=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    [application setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    self.window.clipsToBounds=YES;
    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);

}
```

If you follow the above steps, you don't need to write the code in viewWillAppear of every view controller.